# Adding precision to Ubuntu Calculator unit conversion

Tags: 20.04, calculator

In the Ubuntu calculator, these are the values I get when converting from Millimeters to Inches:

```
6.25 mm = 0.25 in
6.3 mm = 0.25 in
6.35 mm = 0.25 in
6.4 mm = 0.25 in
6.45 mm = 0.25 in
```

[image]

Is there a way to get more precision in the inch value?

This is regarding the conversion functionality in Advanced Mode, not entering the conversion equations in by hand.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Add this information to your question.

Comment: bwroga, you have to press the "To" button that is in between "Millimeters" and "Inches"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

*Result:*

[image]

Open calculator. You will see something like this:

[image: Calculator]

In the top bar, choose "Advanced" instead of "Basic":

[image: Advanced calculator]

Now, to convert length, choose "Length" instead of "Angle":

[image: Change length]

Choose the two measurements you are converting:

[image: Measurements]

Type in your number:

[image: Number]

Finally, press "To" and convert your integer from one measurement to the other:

[image: To]

[image: Converted]

There are also different number formats, like scientific or engineering:

[image: Menu]